# Product imported through magmi dont get saved automatically

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9, magmi

I integrated magmi with magento marketplace , while exporting the products , the products appear in admin panel but dont get assigned to vendor until we open the product one by one and save them , then only it appears in vendor panel of the vendors, we have assigned a vendor id to every vendor and it appears in csv file also ....Please help me and if u can give code ..i would be thankful

Comment: "Please help me and if u can give code" : YOU should provide some code to show people what you tried and explain why it doesn't works :)

Comment: @adee We are not here to finish your work buddy... we are here to help you.